# Compile error - Make error: *** multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a problem with a makefile that's part of a repository. I already posted this question but don't know how to add some code lines after, so I'm trying it here.There is a problem with the makefile that has the common make rules. When I run make, I get the following error: C:\Mios32/include/makefile/common.mk:143: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.

Here's the code from common.mk file from line 142 to 144:

```
# rule to create .elf file                                 
$(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf: $(ALL_OBJS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o$@
```

I'm guessing it's a problem with all_objs, cause these lines right before seem to work:

```
# rule to create a .hex and .bin file                                               
%.bin : $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf
    @$(OBJCOPY) $< -O binary $@
%.hex : $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf
    @$(OBJCOPY) $< -O ihex $@

# rule to create a listing file from .elf                                          
%.lss: $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf
    @$(OBJDUMP) -w -h -S -C $< > $@

# rule to create a symbol table from .elf                                          
%.sym: $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf
    @$(NM) -n $< > $@
```

Here's some additional lines with all_objs:

```
# list of all objects                                                            
ALL_OBJS = $(addprefix $(PROJECT_OUT)/, $(THUMB_OBJS) $(THUMB_CPP_OBJS) $(THUMB_AS_OBJS) 
$(ARM_OBJS) $(ARM_CPP_OBJS) $(ARM_AS_OBJS))

# list of all dependency files                                                 
ALL_DFILES = $(ALL_OBJS:.o=.d)
```

And here's some additional lines with Project_out and project:

```
# where should the output files be located                                    
PROJECT_OUT ?= $(PROJECT)_build

# default linker flags                                                            
LDFLAGS += -T $(LD_FILE) -mthumb -u _start -Wl,--gc-section  -Xlinker -M -Xlinker - 
Map=$(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).map  -nostartfiles -lstdc++

# default rule                                                                       
all: dirs cleanhex $(PROJECT).hex $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).bin 
$(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).lss $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).sym projectinfo

# create the output directories
dirs:
@-if [ ! -e $(PROJECT_OUT) ]; then mkdir $(PROJECT_OUT); fi;
@-$(foreach DIR,$(DIRS), if [ ! -e $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(DIR) ]; \
 then mkdir -p $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(DIR); fi; )
```

I'm pretty new to the whole Make and Makefile topic, so I'm having a hard time figuring out the problem. I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be clear in your question what OS you're working on.  It seems from the error message above you're working on Windows.  The makefile you're trying to use is *very* clearly targeted at a UNIX system like GNU/Linux or possibly MacOS.

If you are not familiar with the differences between Windows and UNIX (which are vast and deep) you will definitely have a lot of learning to do before you can even start to get this working.

To use UNIX environments on Windows you need to use something like WSL, or Cygwin, or at least install a MinGW shell environment.  When you do that you need to be using UNIX paths, not Windows paths.  Windows paths use backslashes (which are escape sequences in UNIX) and drive letters (which have no equivalent in UNIX) and in makefiles in particular the `:` character is special to make so using paths with drive letters is a problem.

You can debug your makefile by adding `$(info ...)` functions to show you the value of variables:

```
# rule to create .elf file
$(info PROJECT_OUT = $(PROJECT_OUT))
$(info PROJECT = $(PROJECT))
$(info ALL_OBJS = $(ALL_OBJS))                                
$(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf: $(ALL_OBJS)
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o$@
```

Comment: I have MSYS installed and am running the makefile from there. Does it maybe have something to do with the Compiler? Should I use some else like MSYS2 or Cygwin? Abd how can I use UNIX paths instead of Windows paths on a Windows machine? Sorry for all the questions, trying to to fight my way to make this work. And do you think a virtual machine with an installed Linux OS would work?

Comment: A VM would be much simpler of course.  All your other questions are specific to your setup and needs and environment and I can't help. I don't know what you mean by "running the makefile from" MSYS.  You mean, you typed `make` in an MSYS bash shell?  That seems unlikely given the error messages you showed above; you won't ever see a Windows path like that in a bash shell.  In any event this doesn't have anything to do with the compiler.  Your makefile never even gets to invoking the compiler, so it's definitely nothing to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I actually typed make from a MSYS bash shell, where I also set the bin folder as an enviromental variable. I now tried it on Linux, which was installed on a VM but I have a different problem there (See my comment). Do you maybe have an idea what to do there? I feel like I'm getting closer to the solution. In the end, I need a project.hex to run on a Microcontroller.

Comment: Here's the link to the complete makefile, if it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xh3knv0jxsshWnCh3xCdfBZgYRkXewTM/view

Comment: If you started make from a bash shell, you definitely don't want to be using Windows-style paths.  But the error you showed us clearly has a Windows-style path: `C:\Mios32/include/makefile/common.mk`.  Running make from a UNIX shell should not have either a drivespec or a backslash.  It looks like you set your `MIOS32_PATH` environment variable to `C:\Mios32` and that's not right if you're using a UNIX shell.  It should be something like `/c/Mios32` or similar.